# if $\int{}f$ is finite, then $\int{}f$ exists?

Tags: lebesgue-integral, lp-spaces

My textbook said,

If $\int_E f$ exists then, of course, $-\infty\le\int_E f\le+\infty$. If $\int_E f$ exists and is finite, we say that $f$ is Lebesgue integrable, or simple integrable, on $E$ and write $f\in L(E)$. Thus, $$L(E)=\left\{f:\int_E f \text { is finite}\right\}$$

---

I think $L(E)$ must be defined by $$L(E)=\left\{f:\int_E f \text { exists and is finite}\right\}$$

---

Why does the textbook omit existence?

Is $f$ in $L(E)$ or not if $\displaystyle\int_E f$ is finite but oscillating.

---

### Add

- Let $f(x)=\sin{x}$. Then $\displaystyle\int_\mathbb{R} f$ is finite, since $\displaystyle\left|\int_\mathbb{R} f(x) dx\right| \le 2 \lt +\infty$. Thus, $f \in L(E)$.
- $\displaystyle\int_\mathbb{R} f$ is oscillating ceaselessly. So it should be said not to exist. Thus, $f\notin L(E)$.

I think the fact that $f\notin L(E)$ is surely correct. However, if $L(E)$ is defined by $\displaystyle\left\{f:\int_E f \text { is finite}\right\}$, $f$ is in $L(E)$. !!

Comment: Being finite implies it exists. $x\in \mathbb R$. How do you know it exists? Do I need to specify that $x$ exists?

Comment: @jdods Here, $E$ is a subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$. Doesn't there exist any cases when $\displaystyle\int_{E}f(\mathbf{x}) d\mathbf{x}$ is changing between two constants depending on how to set partition?

Comment: The existence of the integral means that your choice of a sequence of simple functions, i.e. your choice of sequence of partitions, shouldn't affect the value the approximating integrals converges to.

Comment: Feel free to write "exists and is finite" if you like.  Maybe you can avoid confusing yourself.  But understand that when others write "$\int_E f$ is finite", they include existence without saying it.

Comment: @GEdgar Once, I memorized finiteness includes existence property. However, I don't know why it does.

Comment: Maybe it'd be more clear if you thought about it in terms of signed functions. See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebesgue_integration#Integration) a little further down where it begins "**Signed functions:**". For $f(x) = \sin x$, both $\int_\Bbb{R} f^{+} \, dx$ and $\int_\Bbb{R} f^{-} \, dx$ are infinite, therefore $f \notin L(\Bbb{R})$.  So while it is true that $\int_\Bbb{R} \sin x \, dx$ oscillates in a bounded manner, the integral itself does not exist. I would interpret $|\int_E f| < +\infty$ implying $f \in L(E)$ as a shorthand for $|\int_E f| = M < +\infty$ implies $f \in L(E)$.

Comment: @tilper you made me understood thanks

Comment: No problem, glad to help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $\int_E f$ is finite then it necessarily exists.

**Q:** "Is $f$ in $L(E)$ or not if $\displaystyle \int_E f$ is finite but oscillating."

**A:** If $\int_E f$ is oscillating, then $\int_E f$ doesn't exist.  And since it doesn't exist, then it can't be finite (contrapositive of "if finite, then exists").  Consider $\int_\Bbb{R} \sin x \, dx$ as a concrete example.  It oscillates *between finite values* but the integral itself is not finite (because its value doesn't exist).  So to answer your question, there is no such thing as a "finite but oscillating" integral.  If we rephrase your question to remove "finite but" then the answer is "no, $f$ is not in $L(E)$ in that case."

Comment: Why is $\int_\mathbb{R} \sin{x} dx$ not finite? I think $-2 \le \int_\mathbb{R} \sin{x} dx \le 2$. Also, I have known that $f$ is said to be finite when $|f| \le M$ for a constant $M$.

Comment: As I said, it's not finite because it doesn't exist.  Do you agree with the following statement?  "If it is finite, then it exists."  And are you familiar with the property that a logical statement and its contrapositive always have the same truth value?  If your answer is yes to both of these then you agree that "If it does not exist, then it is not finite" is a true statement.

Comment: And your inequality is true but the point is that $\int_\Bbb{R} \sin x \, dx$ doesn't actually have a value.

Comment: I do not agree with the statement that if $\int f$ is finite, then it exists. Your example is finite, but does not exists.

Comment: If $\int_\Bbb{R}\sin x \, dx$ is finite, then it must have a value.  But it doesn't have a value.  It only oscillates between values.  Oscillating between values is not the same thing as having a value.  Would you also say that $\lim_{x \to +\infty} \sin x$ is finite?  I think you're under the impression that the only two possibilities are finite and infinite.  There is a third possibility, which is "does not exist," and that's the category under which $\int_\Bbb{R} \sin x \, dx$ falls.